# Could [true] & [false] tags be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I think the [boolean](/questions/tagged/boolean) could be used for the questions tagged with [true](/questions/tagged/true) and [false](/questions/tagged/false).  So would it be reasonable to remove these two?